# Lower bound for $\|x-y\|$

Tags: normed-spaces, upper-lower-bounds

For $x$,$y$ in Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ I want a lower bound for
\begin{equation}
\|x-y\|_{\mathcal{H}}^2
\end{equation}
I know 
\begin{equation}
|\ \|x\|_{\mathcal{H}}-\|y\|_{\mathcal{H}}\ |\leq\|x-y\|_{\mathcal{H}} 
\end{equation}
However is there a better answer than this? My Hilbert space is $L^2$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific or give us a context. What you mean by "better"? The inequality is sharp in the sense that there exist pairs $x,y$ such that equality is reached.

Comment: I would like to get rid of the absolute value. I would just like to have $\|x\|$ and $\|y\|$ on the left hand side. Is this even possible? I am trying to find an upper for bound $\|u-v\|^2_{L^2}$.

Comment: note that $r\|x-y\|\le\|x-y\|$ for any $r\in[0,1]$, choose whatever you want :)

Comment: I would like to have $\|x-y\|^2_{L^2}\geq C(\|x\|^2-\|y\|^2)$.

Comment: You can just drop the absolute value, if you like. The inequality gets weaker by doing this.

Comment: I believe $\|x-y\|_{L^2}^2\geq \|x\|^2-\|y\|^2$ is false?

Comment: @CuriousCat The inequality $\|x-y\|^{2} \geq C(\|x\|^{2}-\|x\|^{2})$ does not hold even for real numbers.

Comment: Could you please give me a suggestion as to how to find a lower bound for $\|x-y\|_{L^2}^2$. Thank you for your help.